# where is layout of source

Tags: android-layout

if i want get root view,i also by call getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.content)  or findViewById(android.R.id.content).getRootView().so i want to know if i can find the layout of android.R.id.content. could you tell me where is the layout.you can give me a link or other.thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Hierarchy Viewer tool**, See the definitons and Steps of how to use this tool in developer guide as shown below,

It shows **visual representation of the layout's View** hierarchy (the Layout View) and a magnified inspector of the display (the Pixel Perfect View).

**To get the Hierarchy Viewer started:**

> Connect your device or launch an
>   emulator. From a terminal, launch
>   hierarchyviewer from your SDK /tools
>   directory.   In the window that opens,
>   you'll see a list of Devices.   When a
>   device is selected, a list of
>   currently active Windows is displayed
>   on the right. The  is
>   the window currently in the
>   foreground, and also the default
>   window loaded if you do not select
>   another.  Select the window that you'd
>   like to inspect and click Load View
>   Hierarchy. The Layout View will be
>   loaded. You can then load the Pixel
>   Perfect View by clicking the second
>   icon at the bottom-left of the window.
>   If you've navigated to a different
>   window on the device, press Refresh
>   Windows to refresh the list of
>   available windows on the right.

Now with the help of this tool, it shows the content is in  Frame Layout, pls refer this output given by this tool.

> [image]